# C# serialize DynamoDB item to JSON

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In my C# lambda I retrieve an item from DynamoDB. It is returned as a `Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>`. Is there a good way to serialize that to JSON?

The AttributeValue class exposes a bunch of properties to retrieve values of different types. If you do a simple serialization each one of those properties shows up in the JSON, most of them null, and makes a really messy object.

I want it to recognize a map and turn it into a JSON object, recognize a list and turn it into a JSON list. Basically, I want the object the Item represents.

Comment: Do you want to just serialise the Dictionary? You can use Json.NET to do that. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: It's still a dictionary of AttributeValues and they don't get serialized cleanly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an alternate approach in C# to connect to DynamoDB using the DocumentModel.  This DocumentModel has a ToJson() function.

```
Table table = Table.LoadTable(client, "yourtable");
Document document = table.GetItem(123);
string strJSON = document.ToJson();
```